# Trying to find unused stored procedures, but dm_exec_procedure_stats seems to be resetting

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dmv

I need to identify stored procedures that are no longer used by our application (~2,000 stored procedures, duplicated in ~1,000 databases).

To do this, I'm querying `dm_exec_procedure_stats`, which initially seemed to give good results, until I saw some stored procedures that I know are being used a lot.

Subsequent investigations show that if I run the query a few times in a row, I get records dropping out.

Is this a simple indication of memory pressure causing the cache to be cleared?
Nobody is running `dbcc freeproccache` or `dbcc freesystemcache`.

```
SELECT database_id, object_id, OBJECT_NAME(object_id, database_id) 'Name',
    d.total_elapsed_time, d.execution_count, d.total_worker_time, 
    d.total_logical_reads, d.total_logical_writes
FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS d
WHERE p.name LIKE '%myinterestingsproc%'
```

If, for example, that query returns two rows for 'one' stored procedure  (because it's the same name in two db's, I consider it one stored procedure  for the purposes of utilisation), a subsequent run of the query might lose one of the rows. Numbers of the remaining rows do *not* reset, so it's not a system-wide stats reset.

Comment: I'd almost guarantee you are seeing memory pressure on your cache.  2000 procs on 1000 databases?  That's a lot of caching going on.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. It *is* spread over half a dozen servers, but it's still 2k sprocs in each of the ~200 db's per server. I just wasn't sure if the stats were memory-only, or were stored somewhere out of RAM.